# Simulator require tbd files to run

Tags: xcode8

I am using Xcode 8.3.1 and trying to run my project on simulator but it informs me that I am missing some libraries. Specially:

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.tbd: No such file or directory

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.tbd: No such file or directory
```

I try to find those tbd files to add to Link Binary with Libraries section but I cannot. There are no tbd files in usr/lib folder. Where can I find those tbd files?

Answer (score 0):

there're no *.tbd files in iPhoneSimulator10.3, only *.dylib files exists.

you should:

1. in xcode->project target->build phases->link binary with libraries->delete all *.tbd references
2. in xcode->project target->build settings->linking->other linker flags->add those dependencies: -l, such as: -lxml2 -lsqlite3

[image: linking sample]